# Android: error when requesting photos?

Tags: android, get, uri, android-intent, photos

I am running into an issue with my app that I wasn't running into before hand. What I am trying to do is to allow the option for a user to pic a photo from the device using intents. Then return that photo back to the calling activity to then be displayed in an image view (for now...). Problem is that yesterday everything was working for me and today (...haven't changed anything with the code...) nothing seems to be doing anything at all. It almost seems like the app is "hanging". Not sure how to resolve this or even trouble shoot the root cause of this. If anyone has any suggestions please post, here is the code:

```
//---Pressing this button will allow for user to choose what photo should return---
    Button b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_getPhotos);
    b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        public void onClick(View arg0)
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            //Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            i.setType("image/*");

            //**Keep in mind after calling the StartActivityForResult() it seems to hang...**
            startActivityForResult(i, PIC_REQUEST);

        }

    });
```

Here is the OnActivityResult():

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data )
{   
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED)
    {
       //handles when camera was canceled...
       Toast.makeText(this, "Cancelled by user...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } 

    else if (requestCode == PIC_REQUEST) 
    {   
       Uri photoUri = data.getData();

       try 
       {
            Bitmap galleryPic = Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), photoUri);
            ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.currentPhoto); 
            image.setImageBitmap(galleryPic);

        } 
       catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
       {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
       catch (IOException e) 
       {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Last but not least here is the waring/error log:

```
11-09 10:07:47.060: WARN/InputManagerService(142): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@407d13a8
11-09 10:07:56.330: WARN/ActivityThread(3957): Application king.chad.SDE is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
11-09 10:08:06.250: WARN/ActivityManager(142): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
11-09 10:08:06.320: WARN/ActivityManager(142): Activity idle timeout for ActivityRecord{40939988 king.chad.SDE/.MainActivity}
```

I want to say that my problem lies within this section of the log (based on other forum related issues that I've researched...), but I'm not sure:

```
11-09 10:08:23.090: WARN/InputManagerService(142): Starting input on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@407f37e0 (uid=10022 pid=238)
11-09 10:08:45.890: WARN/InputManagerService(142): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@40ce5140
```

Uninstalled app, re-installed, dubugged, error log on 2nd run:

```
11-09 10:23:59.690: WARN/ActivityManager(142): No content provider found for: 
11-09 10:23:59.700: WARN/PackageParser(142): Unknown element under <manifest>: uses-library at /data/app/vmdl1692687349.tmp Binary XML file line #8
11-09 10:23:59.700: WARN/ActivityManager(142): No content provider found for: 
11-09 10:24:00.730: WARN/ResourceType(273): getEntry failing because entryIndex 1041 is beyond type entryCount 185
11-09 10:24:00.760: WARN/ResourceType(273): Failure getting entry for 0x7f020411 (t=1 e=1041) in package 0 (error -2147483647)
11-09 10:24:00.760: WARN/ResourceType(273): getEntry failing because entryIndex 1042 is beyond type entryCount 185
11-09 10:24:00.760: WARN/ResourceType(273): Failure getting entry for 0x7f020412 (t=1 e=1042) in package 0 (error -2147483647)
11-09 10:24:00.760: WARN/ResourceType(273): getEntry failing because entryIndex 1043 is beyond type entryCount 185
11-09 10:24:00.760: WARN/ResourceType(273): Failure getting entry for 0x7f020413 (t=1 e=1043) in package 0 (error -2147483647)
11-09 10:24:00.760: WARN/ResourceType(273): getEntry failing because entryIndex 1420 is beyond type entryCount 185
11-09 10:24:00.760: WARN/ResourceType(273): Failure getting entry for 0x7f02058c (t=1 e=1420) in package 0 (error -2147483647)
11-09 10:24:00.770: WARN/ResourceType(273): getEntry failing because entryIndex 223 is beyond type entryCount 185
11-09 10:24:00.770: WARN/ResourceType(273): Failure getting entry for 0x7f0200df (t=1 e=223) in package 0 (error -2147483647)
11-09 10:24:01.500: WARN/ActivityThread(5952): Application king.chad.SDE is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
11-09 10:24:11.330: WARN/ActivityManager(142): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
11-09 10:24:11.470: WARN/ActivityManager(142): Activity idle timeout for ActivityRecord{408a9dc8 king.chad.SDE/.MainActivity}
11-09 10:24:14.510: WARN/InputManagerService(142): Starting input on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@407f37e0 (uid=10022 pid=238)
11-09 10:24:53.730: WARN/InputManagerService(142): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@4090b358
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, not sure why the above code wasn't working, but I did find a work around for this. After much reading and searching I found that this issue may not actually be related to my code but the device that I was using. I ended up altering the startActivityForResult() method by changing:

```
startActivityForResult(i, PIC_REQUEST);
```

...to this:

```
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "Select a photo"), PIC_REQUEST);
```

...and now all is well. Hope this helps any of you that may encounter the same issue.